# Meaning of the syntax "ContextRegistrar_##ContextType"

Tags: c++, macros, unreal-engine4

I am struggling to understand what the following *#define* does exactly.

```
#define REGISTER_CONTEXT( ContextType ) static const FContextRegistrar ContextRegistrar_##ContextType( ContextType::StaticClass() );
REGISTER_CONTEXT(UBlueprintContext);
```

As far as i know it adds a *UClass* to an array, so that it can be used by a other function and iterated through. But what does the

> ContextRegistrar_##ContextType

do in this context? Can anyone give me a hint please?
This is causing me an runtime crash and I couldn't find something similar.

This is the corresponding struct:

```
struct FContextRegistrar
{
    static TArray<TSubclassOf<UBlueprintLibraryBase>>& GetTypes()
    {
        static TArray<TSubclassOf<UBlueprintLibraryBase>> Types;
        return Types;
    }

    FContextRegistrar( TSubclassOf<UBlueprintLibraryBase> ClassType )
    {
        GetTypes().Add( ClassType );
    }
};
```

Comment: It's token concatenation, read up on it here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## is a token pasting operator in C and C++ preprocessor. You can create new tokens using it. For example:

#define MACRO(x) x ## 1

This macro creates a new token that is same as its argument x, but with 1 appended to it. If you invoke it like `MACRO(1)` the result would be integer literal 11, result of `MACRO(a)` would be a1 which you could use as a name of variable, function, class, etc.

In your example the `REGISTER_CONTEXT(UBlueprintContext);` would produce the following code:

```
static const FContextRegistrar ContextRegistrar_UBlueprintContext( UBlueprintContext::StaticClass() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to concatenate tokens in macros, see [Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Thus, in your case: `REGISTER_CONTEXT(Bar)` in your program will expand to `ContextRegistrar_Bar` as part of the macro.

Comment: Not strings, tokens.